# How change base url in angular project

Tags: angular

I want to change the base url in `index.html`

when load the application url is `http://localhost:4200/#/` I want to change this to `http://localhost:4200/#/carrom`.

For doing this I changed base url to `<base href="/carrom">` then loading url is `http://localhost:4200/carrom#/`

How can I change this to `http://localhost:4200/#/carrom`

Comment: What you want is just a route, nothing to do with base url (that would still be /index.html). Are you sure you don’t mean http://localhost:4200/carrom/# /

Comment: Also.. is there a reason you want to use hash urls..? Just curious..?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing wanted value with `APP_BASE_HREF` injection token in your `AppModule`. Something like this:

```js
...
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ....
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
  ....
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '#/carrom'}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: APP_BASE_HREF is for PathLocationStrategy not HashLocationStrategy